# Migrated question spoils my accept rate

Tags: support, questions, accept-rate, migrated-questions

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136280/killing-the-windows-shell-closed) over at SO was closed and moved to SU, which is perfectly fine.

But now it still lives on as a zombie in SO and I can't accept anything, vote to delete it, or do anything else.

I wouldn't have brought up this and would have let it live its un-life, if it was for the question alone. But since the accept rate is displayed, this silly question spoils my rate, and that for no good reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063228) is the question "hurting" your acceptance rate. Questions that are closed, CW or not 3 days old are excluded from the calculation for acceptance rate. Additionally as [TheTXI suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23307/moved-question-spoils-my-acception-rate/23308#23308), a 100% acceptance rate is not important at all, your acceptance rate as is, suggests you will generally accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake calculating the rate, never should tell anyone my scientific background :-(

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be attaching so much importance to your Acceptance Rate to begin with. I would personally look upon someone with a super high acceptance rate as someone who is willing to accept any answer rather than waiting for the right answer or one that actually works.